# Change the range of existing partition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I have a table with two partitions:

```
create table MY
(
  id           NUMBER not null,
  dat          DATE
)
partition by range (dat)
(
  partition PART_ARCHIVE values less than (TO_DATE(' 2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) 
  tablespace ARCHIVE,
  partition PART_ACTUAL values less than (MAXVALUE) tablespace ACTUAL

);
```

Can I change the `PART_ARCHIVE` partition date interval without recreating table?

I need to set that:

```
 partition PART_ARCHIVE values less than (TO_DATE(' 2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether you can do it in a single command but this one should work:

```
ALTER TABLE MY SPLIT PARTITION PART_ACTUAL INTO
  (PARTITION PART_2017 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2017-01-01'),
   PARTITION PART_ACTUAL);

ALTER TABLE MY MERGE PARTITIONS PART_2017, PART_ARCHIVE INTO PART_ARCHIVE;
```